# Drag and drop within list, windows 8 app?

Tags: c#, list, xaml, windows-8, drag-and-drop

Is there any good examples/tutorials on how to implement drag and drop within a window 8 C# list (listview, listbox …) out there?

What I would like Is a  editable “Iphone-list”-experience, where  I easily can rearrange items within a list. But I mostly find WinJS examples and I would like to have a c# example for win 8

Answer (score 0):

Firstly You must enable the **AllowDragDrop** property.

Then write 3 events:

```
    private void myList_ItemDrag(object sender, ItemDragEventArgs e)
    {
        DoDragDrop(e.Item, DragDropEffects.Link);
    }

    private void myList_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Link;
    }

    private void myList_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        // do whatever you need to reorder the list.
    }
```

To get index of dropped item:

```
Point cp = myList.PointToClient(new Point(e.X, e.Y));
ListViewItem dragToItem = myList.GetItemAt(cp.X, cp.Y);
int dropIndex = dragToItem.Index;
```

Comment: First of all, I didn’t find a AllowDragDrop property  on, in my case, ListBox. Have you any special component in mind for this?

Secondly, it will be a lot of work to get a smooth experience with all what it means (drag and scroll, show where the object will land, and so forth) Isn’t there any win8 component, framework or likewise out there?

Comment: This is examle for ListView control.

Comment: Ok, what I can see listview and listbox neither has ItemDrag, dragDrop or AllowDragDrop. Am I missing something?

Comment: There's AllowDrop and CanDragItems

Answer (score 0):

If you need to drop onto a ListView or GridView, have the Drop event fire on the DataTemplate for the actual Item, not the whole list.   Then you can tell which item it is dropped on.